# How many times can I benefit from Advantage if I attack multiple times while not seen?

Tags: dnd-5e, surprise, advantage-and-disadvantage

A hidden ranger with Extra Attack attacks a surprised creature. Do both attacks benefit from Advantage, or just the first one?

If the ranger used Horde Breaker on another creature, would this attack benefit from Advantage?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the PHB, page 195:

> If you are hidden—both unseen and unheard—when you make an attack, you give away your location when the attack hits or misses.

So, **the first attack is rolled with Advantage**, but it reveals the attacker's position, so **all consecutive attacks lose the advantage**.

Make note that the rule does not state that only the attacked creature notices the attacker. Instead, **all creatures that are able to see or hear the attack notice the attacker** when he makes his first attack. If they can't see the attacker directly because the line of sight is obstructed, they still know roughly where he is.

Arguably, if the Ranger is in a position to Hide again from his secondary target (e.g. the Ranger is hidden from him behind a tree), he could do that and once again attack with advantage. However, hiding requires its own action, so the Ranger would have to have a special ability to Hide on the same turn as it's attacking.

Comment: Certain ranger abilities allow you to keep hidden if you miss your first attack. Might be relevant information :)

Comment: I'm having trouble following this answer, attacking while unseen gives you advantage, and if you attack while hidden then you give away your location. Then there is an unexplained gap and after that you no longer have advantage? How did giving away your location prevent you from having advantage? An invisible creature has known location, and it can be heard, but it still attacks with advantage right? Additionally, don't hidden creatures not normally make sound? Can they be detected just by hearing? The unseen attackers say hidden creatures are "unseen and unheard" right?

Comment: @jgn When you're hiding, you're the one making sure that you're unseen and unheard. A person trying to remain hidden will not attempt to do things they know will reveal their location, and thus are limited in what they can do. And the PHB states that you cannot attack someone and remain hidden. So when you attack, you do so knowing that it will reveal your position. So the sequence goes: 1.)You hide and enemies lose track of you. 2.)You make your first attack with advantage. 3.)Enemies notice your attack, and you're no longer hidden. 4.)Your second attack is made normally, without advantage.

Comment: @jgn Invisible creatures are special in that they don't need to make any effort to remain unseen, and can be unseen in plain sight. So Invisibility was made into a condition that effectively gives creatures auto-hiding. But you can still tell their location by sound to be able to fight them at all.
For everyone else,if your location is known it means your enemy can normally defend from your attacks, and can either walk to you or target your location with an attack. You can still stay behind cover to avoid most ranged attacks, but to attack you must briefly exit your cover,which gets you seen.

Comment: @DaFluid I think the PHB states you cannot approach someone and remain hidden, not that you can't attack. Moreover, there are rules for attacking while hidden in the unseen attackers section. It is step 3 that I'm not sure about. The rules explicitly say that your location is revealed, not that enemies automatically detect you. Where do you get this idea from? Not only that, but your idea seems to imply that knowing someones location is the same as being able to see them, which the same rules section says is not the same thing.

Comment: @jgn I imply the reverse: not being seen atm doesn't mean you're hidden.If you're hiding under a blanket someone might not notice you,but if you peek your arm out to throw a shoe at them they will know you're there,despite you covering yourself up again.In a combat situation where everyone is on alert,having your location known is enough to thwart your attempts at secretly attacking someone. "Your location is revealed" means "the creatures in the encounter know your location".If an NPC were hidden you would not know until it attacked, and then the DM would tell you where the attack came from.

Comment: @DaFluid Knowing someone's location isn't enough to be able to detect them, see them, and does not let you ignore the penalties for attacking an unseen targets, nor deny them the advantages for being an unseen attacker. There are separate rules for attacking an unseen target, and attacking a target with unknown location. The rules for hiding explicitly differentiate being detected and having a known location. I really don't see why, considering how far the rules go to differentiate, you can conclude that it's the same thing and that knowing someones location is enough to break hiding.

Comment: @jgn I never said they were the same thing, and this difference in what I say and what you comprehend makes me feel my explanations are inadequate (having limited characters does not help). I suggest you post your own answer, completely laying out your line of thought along with backup from rules and we can go from there. Hopefully others engage in the conversation and we can find the right answer together.

Comment: @DaFluid This rule "If you are hidden—both unseen and unheard—when you make an attack, you give away your location when the attack hits or misses." followed by this sentence "So, the first attack is rolled with Advantage, but it reveals the attacker's position, so all consecutive attacks lose the advantage." seems to say that having your position revealed means you are revealed. You then go on to say "all creatures that are able to see or hear the attack notice the attacker", again not really explaining how all this happens just from knowing someone's location. The leap is confusing.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the above answer, **if** you are unseen and unheard, **then** you have advantage. **Normally** making an attack reveals you.
**However**, certain combinations of effects could negate this, **such as** being under the effects of *greater invisibility*, *silence* and *mirror image* all at the same time, because:

1. *Greater Invisibility* allows you to make the attack while remaining **unseen**.
2. *Silence* prevents creatures from detecting you with sound, as they are deafened, thus allowing you to attack while remaining **unheard**.
3. Finally, *Mirror Image* consistently changes your location, preventing them from determining your location by knowing where your attack came from. The combination of the three should prevent you from being located by virtue of the mechanics of *mirror image* and the other two fulfilling the requirements for being hidden. Based on the mechanics, you only have a 30% chance to be detected when you make a such an attack with three duplicates, and a 40% chance with two. This is slightly houserule, as the spell's rules do not cover shifting except when being attacked. However, perception checks to determine which one is real use the same mechanics normally, and this is a similar logical extension of the rules, as well as a worthwhile use of a 3rd-level spell and two 2nd-level spells.

Comment: It is preferred that answers [independently address the question](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3326/23970); I suspect your "add-on" structure may garner downvotes. I suggest you review the advice in the linked meta post and re-work this answer to present as an independent answer to OP's question. (You could even delete the post while you work on it, then undelete it in a better form as a way to "protect" it from downvotes while in a nascent state.)

Answer (score -1):

## You have advantage on all attacks made while unseen

The rules for [Unseen Attackers and Targets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#UnseenAttackersandTargets) clearly states:

> When a creature can't see you, you have advantage on attack rolls against it.

### Attacking while hidden does not mean people can see you

If you are hidden at the time, the rules add:

> If you are hidden--both unseen and unheard--when you make an attack, you **give away your location** when the attack hits or misses.

**Having your location revealed does not mean you have been detected.** There are many places in the rules that talk about the difference between being seen, detected, and having a known location, including the rules for unseen targets:

> Combatants often try to escape their foes' notice by hiding, casting the invisibility spell, or lurking in darkness.

Being hidden, invisible, or in darkness do not cause you to stop being detectable with other senses, nor do they hide your location. For example a creature walking around with invisibility can be heard and their location is known.

It also contains different rules for attacking a target when you know or don't know their location:

> When you attack a target that you can't see, you have disadvantage on the attack roll. This is true whether you're guessing the target's location or you're targeting a creature you can hear but not see. If the target isn't in the location you targeted, you automatically miss, but the DM typically just says that the attack missed, not whether you guessed the target's location correctly.

The rules for [Hiding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Hiding) also make a distinction:

> You can't hide from a creature that can see you clearly, and **you give away your position** if you make noise, such as shouting a warning or knocking over a vase.

Making noise only gives away your position, it does not "break hiding" or let creatures automatically detect you. The rules for unseen attackers mirrors this wording. There is no uncertain terms, having your location revealed does not mean you are detected.

The [Skulker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/skulker) feat also makes the same distinction:

> When you are hidden from a creature and miss it with a ranged weapon attack, making the attack doesn't **reveal your position**.

### When Hidden and using Extra Attack and Hordebreaker, you have advantage on all attacks

Here is the chain of events:

1. The Ranger finds a DM approved hiding spot and the DM calls for a Stealth Check
2. The DM determines of the Ranger beats the passive perception of the enemies, in this example they do
3. The Ranger attacks:

   - They are unseen and so have advantage.
   - They are hidden, so when the attack hits or misses, their location is revealed.
4. Repeat step 3 for Hordebreaker, and Extra Attack

At the end of this sequence, the Ranger has attacked 3 times with advantage, and has given away their location 3 times. They remain hidden, unseen, and unheard (although your DM may rule that their actions have made sufficient noise to reveal their location again).

The Ranger can now stealthily move away from their location since the enemy will likely attack that position. However enemies can try and guess the Ranger's new position, and they will most likely send someone to investigate the position by moving to gain line of sight, and also using the Search action.