# Do all of the melee spell attacks from Steel Wind Strike have advantage if the caster is under the effect of the Invisibility spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility, advantage-and-disadvantage

The [Invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/invisibility) spell (PHB, p. 254) says:

> A creature you touch becomes **invisible** until the spell ends. Anything the target is wearing or carrying is invisible as long as it is on the target's person. The spell ends for a target that attacks or casts a spell.

And the spell [Steel Wind Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/steel-wind-strike) (XGE, p. 166) says:

> You flourish the weapon used in the casting and then vanish to strike like the wind. Choose up to five creatures you can see within range. Make a melee spell attack against each target. On a hit, a target takes 6d10 force damage.

If a spellcaster under the effect of an Invisibility spell casts Steel Wind Strike, would they have advantage on all five melee spell attacks, or only on the first one?

Comment: And welcome to the stack! Please take our [tour] to learn more about us and you can also visit the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more info.

Comment: Related: "[When attacking while invisible, when exactly does invisibility break?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103510)", "[How many times can I benefit from Advantage if I attack multiple times while not seen?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69540)", and "[How can you get advantage from invisibility if attacking ends it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64892)"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Please note that this answer assumes that* steel wind strike *does not naturally grant advantage on all its attacks (even without invisibility).  I believe this is the intended interpretation, but it may not be the RAW reading -- see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176830).*

### Either the first one, or none of them.

Take *eldritch blast* as precedent, as the wording is similar.  *Eldritch blast* calls for ranged spell attacks against multiple targets, specifically making "a separate attack roll for each beam" (PHB p.237), similar enough to *steel wind strike*'s "make a melee spell attack against each target."

The [*Sage Advice Compendium*](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) reads as follows, in response to a question asking whether the beams from *eldritch blast* are simultaneous:

> Even though the duration of each of these spells is instantaneous, you choose the targets and resolve the attacks consecutively, not all at once. If you want, you can declare all your targets before making any attacks, but you would still roll separately for each attack (and damage, if appropriate).
>
> SA-C p.12

Thus, since each attack happens in series, and *invisibility* ends *either* when you attack or cast a spell, there are two distinct points when the invisibility could end.  If "casting a spell" is considered to occur when you begin casting a spell, then you become visible before any attacks are made.  Otherwise, it will last until the first attack breaks *invisibility*, and that one attack will be made with advantage.

So the issue rests on when the character is considered to have cast a spell.  I'm not aware of an official ruling that would make this determination, but if one exists, it will be the determining factor.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because yours is better. I forgot that there was a Sage Advice ruling the specifically calls out attacks being resolved sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

#### You have advantage on every attack.

You would have advantage on all of the attacks, but not because of the effect of *invisibility*.

First, we understand that [there is no flavor text in spell descriptions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/78022/62294).

That said, the following sentence is rules, not flavor:

> You flourish the weapon used in the casting and then vanish to strike like the wind.

*You vanish*. If you vanish, you are unseen. [If you are unseen, then](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#UnseenAttackersandTargets):

> When a creature can't see you, you have advantage on attack rolls against it.

You are an unseen attacker for each attack of *steel wind strike*, so they would be made with advantage.